# how do i register .xap mime type in IIS 6 programatically

Tags: c#, silverlight, iis-6

i want to register .xap mime type for a particular site in IIS6

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can only add them manually.

Go to `Run` >> "`inetmgr`"

Right click on your computer (Local Computer) and click on `Properties`

Select `MIME Types`, then "`New`".

Type "`.xap`" for Extension and "`application/x-silverlight-app`" for MIME-Type.